# The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

could someone please help with this, i am trying to get data from firestore and loop through to create a list but i keep getting an error

The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.

the getter its talking about is .data at this part in my for loop brackets below  for( var i = 0; i < roomsSnapshot.data.documents.length; i++ )

```
checkDatabase() {

 var docSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('rooms')
        .where('link' , isEqualTo: documentSnapshot.id)
        .snapshots();




         return docSnapshot;

     }


     var roomsSnapshot = checkDatabase();

     List hotels;

 for( var i = 0; i < roomsSnapshot.data.documents.length;  i++  ){


                               DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                 hotels.add(
HotelCard(
          title:  documentSnapshot.data()['name'],
          subTitle: documentSnapshot.data()['sub'],
          imageAsset:  documentSnapshot.data()['image'],
        ))

}
```